# Difference between the transformation and change of basis matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I've trying to understand the difference between the matrix representation of a linear transformation $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and the change of basis matrix $P \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. I understand that for a linear transformation $L:V \to W$ the transformation matrix takes a vector $v \in V$ and transforms it into a vector $Ax = L(v) \in W$ with $x = [x]_{\beta}$ the coordinate vector w.r.t. a basis $\beta$ of $V$. On the other hand the  change of basis matrix is a linear transformation $L_A:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}: [x]_{\beta} \mapsto P \cdot [x]_{\beta} = [x]_{\alpha}$ mapping the coordinate vector from on basis $\beta$  to another basis $\alpha$ of the same subspace $V$.

Can someone confirm and/or correct my reasoning on this topic. Much appreciated

Comment: I usually interpet these two meaning thinking to coordinate trasformation of Galileo.

Comment: The matrix representation of a linear transformation $L:V\to W$ is dependent on the basis of both $V$ and $W$. So there can be many matrices associated with a linear transformation depending on what basis you choose.